# Data is not send from View to Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to send an object from a razor view to a controller method in ASP.NET MVC 5.The issue is that the object is not sent to the controller.This is my View:

```
 @using Models;
@{ 
    var ListedCompanies = ViewBag.ListedCompanies as IEnumerable<Company>;
}
@model Models.Individual
```

```
<head>

</head>

<body>     
    <div style="width:70% ; float :left">
        <table id="verticalScroll" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm" cellspacing="0">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        CompanyName
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        SharePrice
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        SharesCount
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        SharesOnTheMarket
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Details
                    </th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                @foreach (Company o in ListedCompanies)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @o.CompanyName
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @o.SharePrice
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @o.SharesCount
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @o.SharesOnTheMarket
                        </td>
                        <td>

                            <button type="button" value="Details" class="btn btn-primary"
                                    onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Transaction","User", new Transaction { Company = o,Individual = (Individual)Model})'">
                                Details
                            </button>

                        </td>

                    </tr>
                }

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

</body>
```

And this is the controller method:

```
    public ActionResult Transaction(Transaction Transaction)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("CompanyDetails", Transaction);
    }
```

This is the Transaction object :

```
   public class Transaction
{
    public ASK ASK { get; set; }
    public BID BID { get; set; }
    public Individual Individual { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }

}
```

The issue is that when I click the button,the proprieties of the  Transaction object from the controller method are all null.
I tried using [HTTPPost] tag,and also to use a form instead of a button,like this:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Transaction", "User", FormMethod.Post, new Transaction {Company = o,Individual = (Individual)Model}))
   {
      <input type="hidden" name="Transaction" />
      <input type="submit" value="Transaction" class="btn btn-primary active" />
   }
```

Also,did not worked.I also tried to add the method from controller in RouteConfig and I have the same result.

Comment: The `Transaction` object might not be serializing the way you expect it.  In the resulting client-side code ("view source" in the browser), what is the actual URL being rendered by `Url.Action`?

Comment: This is the rendered link:
location.href='/User/Transaction?Individual=System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Individual_38FCAB5A9CFA20BF79D8EDBDD997A0CA040A96BD2C33DAB33CB4A343BE8BDF7B&Company=System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Company_5BF87B6217AD9FE8C136ECD77D64A8AE5DC9669791BB1FEA512FD500FE1CCFE4'

Comment: That would be why then.  You're serializing a pretty complex object.  Even in the model you're showing, each property is itself another object.  What do those objects look like?  Ultimately what specific data do you need to post to the server?  It's highly unusual to send an entire object to the client just to send the entire thing back to the server unmodified.  Usually one just uses a single identifier to fetch the object on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to serialize an entire complex object here:

```
onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Transaction","User", new Transaction { Company = o,Individual = (Individual)Model})'"
```

From a comment on the question above, it's just writing the string representation of each property:

```
location.href='/User/Transaction?Individual=System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Individual_38FCAB5A9CFA20BF79D8EDBDD997A0CA040A96BD2C33DAB33CB4A343BE8BDF7B&Company=System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Company_5BF87B6217AD9FE8C136ECD77D64A8AE5DC9669791BB1FEA512FD500FE1CCFE4'
```

Take a step back... Why do you need the *entire object* here?  Consider it conceptually for a moment.  The server is building this whole object, sending this whole object to the client, only to have the client send this whole object *unmodified by the user* back to the server.  (Or at least the *intent* is for the user to not modify it.  What happens when the user *does* modify it?  Will the server trust this entire object when it posts back?)

Ultimately... Why?  There's no need to send the entire object to the client just to send the entire object back to the server.  All the server needs is enough information to re-fetch the object from data.  An identifier of some kind.  In a database this is usually a primary key field.

(Note: The user can still modify the identifier.  Make sure you validate that the information coming from the client is valid for the current logged-in user.)

So what identifiers do you need?  It looks like you are only looking for the `Company` and the `Individual`.  Let's assume for the sake of example that they both have a property called `ID` which is a single value to identify those records in your data.  Then all you need are those identifiers:

```
onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Transaction","User", new { companyID = o.ID, individualID = ((Individual)Model).ID }'"
```

This would render a link more like:

```
location.href='/User/Transaction?companyID=123&individualID=234'
```

In the server-side action you would then expect just those values:

```
public ActionResult Transaction(int companyID, int individualID)
{
    // Fetch the records to build your Transaction object
}
```

As an aside, it's also worth noting that your action currently re-serializes the whole object again and sends it back to the client again in the form of a redirect.  It looks like there are several levels of indirection happening here, and you're trying to pass an entire object back and forth between the server and the client multiple times.  There's definitely no need for that.

Keep the data between the server and client minimal, only pass around the values that are necessary.  The server can re-construct objects from data faster and more reliably than the network can transmit the entire objects multiple times, and the code will be simpler in doing so.

Comment: After you said that the object might not be serializing correctly I tried to to use JSON.Serialize from NewtonSoft to serialize the object.The issue was that Individual object had a property named Account which acted as a foreign key for another entity in Entity Framework.When I tried to serialize the object i received an error that the Account object was disposed.I did not received this error at first so I did not know where it came from until I tried to serialize the object.I used only identifiers for those objects and it worked.